# Turbolinks, dynamic import(file.js), d3 reloads

Tags: javascript, d3.js, turbolinks, dynamic-import, stimulusjs

#### REPRODUCTION: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/noisy-wax

I'm using Stimulus with Turbolinks and I need to dynamic import many js in controllers.

The code I'm using in `main.js` is:

```js
window.Turbolinks.start()

window.application = window.Stimulus.Application.start()

const IsPreviewPage = () => document.documentElement.hasAttribute('data-turbolinks-preview')

const divID = 'about_graphic'

window.application.register("about", class extends window.Stimulus.Controller {
  async initialize () {
    console.log("About, initialize()")

    if (IsPreviewPage()) {
      return
    }  

    const aboutD3 = await import("./about.js")
    aboutD3.loadChart()
  }
})
```

#### THE PROBLEM

If I navigate to `/about` the first time the chart appears.

Then I navigate to `/index`.

When I come back on the `/about` page the `d3` chart reloads itself (you can see a blink after the preview page by turbolinks).

**How can I avoid the reload?**

In this one, I'm not using dynamic import and it doesn't reload: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mud-shop

Answer (score 1):

The solution is put`<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview">`
in the head. Regards